# Script to set sudo timeout

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, sudo, timeout

I would like to use a script to change the sudo timeout of a machine in an automated fashion. Everything I've found online related to changing the sudo timeout is in regards to `visudo` and manually using an editor to adjust the  timeout as follows:

```
Defaults        env_reset, timestamp_timeout=XX
```

How can I create this as part of an automated bash script with no user input? Is there a system file I can overwrite? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried /etc/sudo.conf? Mind that if you misconfigure it you may end up disabling it for your own user, and then not being able to fix it easily. visudo does some checking to avoid it.

Comment: You should be able to drop a file into `/etc/sudoers.d` with the `Defaults timestamp_timeout=xx` setting.